# Contacts Synchronisation in ios

Tags: ios, addressbook, whatsapp

I requires Address book synchronisation whenever new contact adds.

Like:WhatsApp Like Listing of all the contacts who are available on the App.
When New contact has been added , How to compare with others contacts ? I want to highlight New contacts which are added newly.

Comment: Hi, No i just drop that idea not now.

Answer (score 0):

For IOS8, 
While fetching addressbook ,declare callback method like this ,

```
 ABAddressBookRef book = ABAddressBookCreate();
 ABAddressBookRegisterExternalChangeCallback(book,MyAddressBookExternalChangeCallback, (__bridge void *)(self));
```

And you will be notified through this method,

```
void MyAddressBookExternalChangeCallback (
                                      ABAddressBookRef addressBok,
                                      CFDictionaryRef info,
                                      void *context
                                      )
{

}
```

For IOS9,
Use this notification while fetching contacts through CNcontact ,

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(CNcontactDidChange:) name:CNContactStoreDidChangeNotification object:nil];
```